# Converting base 64 coloured image string to grayscale image base 64

Tags: javascript, java, image-processing

Is it possible to get grayscale base 64 string from base 64 of coloured image in  javascript or java ?Thanks.

Comment: Yes (and: Java != JavaScript)

Comment: @Andreas -Thanks for your reply.I know Java!= javascript.But im working on frontend as well as backend.So I just want to check if it is possible from UI(Javascript) or from backend(java).Could you please share some reference material for that.

Comment: Googling your question good have get you the answer : https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Grayscale_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it can be done in JS, and I guess it can be done in Java too :)

Example: [PEN](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/BRMxXy)

The easiest possible way:

```
context.filter = 'grayscale(100%)'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Exactly as I wanted.